# mediafilepicker cannot display pdf files

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm currently using the `nativescript-mediafilepicker` to upload files. I want the user to pick files regardless of the file extension but the only file shwon by the application is a `jpg` file. What seems to be the problem here?

```
public openCustomFilesPicker() {
        let extensions = [];

        if (Application.ios) {
            extensions = [kUTTypePDF, kUTTypeText];
        } else {
            extensions = ["txt", "pdf", "jpg"];
        }

        let options: FilePickerOptions = {
            android: {
                extensions: extensions,
                maxNumberFiles: 2,
            },
            ios: {
                extensions: extensions,
                multipleSelection: true,
                hostView: this._hostView,
            },
        };

        let mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
        mediafilepicker.openFilePicker(options);

        mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
            let results = res.object.get("results");
            console.dir(results);

            if (results) {
                for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    let result = results[i];
                    console.log(result.file);
                }
            }
        });

        mediafilepicker.on("error", function (res) {
            let msg = res.object.get("msg");
            console.log(msg);
        });

        mediafilepicker.on("cancel", function (res) {
            let msg = res.object.get("msg");
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
```